# (Partial) symmetry order for matrices

Tags: matrices, terminology, order-theory

Does there exists commonly used ( possible partial) orderings which would rank matrices as a function of their "degree of symmetry"?

I am thinking one could for instance have $\succeq_{SYM}$ defined as :

> For any two matrices $A,B$ with the same dimensions, if $|a_{ij} -a_{ji}| \leq |b_{ij} - b_{ji}|$
>    for every $i,j$, then $A \succeq_{SYM} B$.

Does this partial ordering has a commonly used name? Do you know of others which would be in use?

Comment: Thanks for the accept -- perhaps you should unaccept and let the question be listed as unanswered, though; surely there's more to say about this than my off-the-cuff suggestion. (For example I have no idea how hard that is to compute).

Comment: Thanks for following up on the question. Sounds like a good idea. I'll leave it unaccepted at least a little longer.

Comment: Maybe one can generalize your idea by using something like $A\succeq_{SYM} B$ iff $||A-A^T||\leq ||B-B^T||$, where $||\cdot||$ is a matrix norm.

Answer (score 1):

That ordering sounds very basis-dependent. How about something based on the fact that exactly the symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable? For example, define the "asymmetry" of $A$ as
$$ \operatorname{asym} A = \inf_{P\in\mathrm{SO}(n), \Delta\text{ diagonal}} \|P^{\sf t}AP-\Delta\|$$
where $\|{\cdot}\|$ is some appropriate matrix norm.

A matrix would then be more symmetric than another if it has smaller asymmetry.